# How to user a 'greater than' PHP statement with MySQL Decimals

Tags: php, mysql

I have a decimal(15,2) field in my MySQL database named 'price'. 
I would like to do something like this with PHP:

```
<? 
    $price = $row->price;
    if($price >= 75) { echo 'Free Delivery'; }
?>
```

Do I need to turn $price into an integer before doing this? If so, what's the best way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: did u tried to echo $price; before if statement to check if it looks good? What error do u have?

Comment: No you don't have to typecast it.

Comment: ah ha.... fixed it. The shopping cart I'm using was adding the currency symbol before passing it to the view! Should've checked that first. Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shopping cart I'm using was adding the currency symbol before passing it to the view! Should've checked that first. Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 1):

you could use explode() function to get the portions of the string before and after the decimal point. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$parts = explode('.', $price);
if($parts[0] >= 75){ echo "free delivery"; }
```

Comment: It's pointless to explode number to recive int. You don't have to do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

I preferr to store prices in smallest units that are used. If the smallest is cent, so why not just to store cents as normal INT? That will solve many problems and will be fast.